# Different encoding on different environment of same web application

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, vaadin7, wildfly-8, diacritics

I have a web-application running on WildFly 8.2.
The application has a view, with links to txt-files.

I have the application running on a local WildFly and on a remote "test" server. Both environments have exactly the same version of the application and same version of WildFly. I also try them with the same web browser (Internet Explorer) on different tabs.

When I click one of those links, using the same web browser, in the application that runs on my local wildfly, it shows the umlaut (äöå) perfectly. In the test environment it doesn't. It shows just empty white boxes.

Now, when I right-click on the page on internet explorer. I can see that in the correctly working version the encoding shows "Western European (Windows)" and in the NOT working, test environment, the encoding shows "Unicode (UTF-8)" being used on the site.

Is there a configuration in WildFly that determines this? Because I'm running the same version of the program in the same branch in both instances so the problem shouldn't be programmatical.

Comment: Do you mean to say, file content is not being shown correctly?

Comment: @Patton, yes I do

Comment: Can you please show your code? I would like to see on how you are reading data from the file?